# iPad Rotation Animation Lag

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have an iPad app that needs to display a unique layout for Portrait and Landscape. I am using viewWillTransitionToSize to make this happen. I have two containers views, which each have a view controller, so my method looks like this:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        let methodStart = NSDate()
        let vc1Size = CGSizeMake(size.width * 0.6, size.height)
        let vc2Size = CGSizeMake(size.width * 0.4, size.height)
        self.viewController1.viewWillTransitionToSize(vc1Size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        self.viewController2.viewWillTransitionToSize(vc2Size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        self.configureSubmitButton()
        let methodFinish = NSDate()
        let executionTime = methodFinish.timeIntervalSinceDate(methodStart)
        print("Execution time: \(executionTime)")
    }
```

My log out put looks like this :

```
Execution time: 0.0536490082740784
```

So viewWillTransitionToSize is not the culprit. After I get this log output, there is a long lag before the rotation animation occurs. I mainly want to know what other methods are firing after viewWillTransitionToSize that I could investigate. The layout looks fine once it rotates, this is just taking too much time.

Comment: Why are you not using the Time Profiler to find exactly how long each piece of code takes? Then you can make an informed decision about what code to look at and what code to optimise instead of guessing.